# A control like panel in the Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crystal-reports, panel

When i use Panel Control,The control's that Panel Contains,the Top and Left properties are set from panel start.
For example if i have a Label that putted in a Panel,if i have Label.Left = 100 ,this property means 100 pixel from the Container panel start,not from form start.
I search for a Control like this in Crystal Reports.The Box Object not like this.
This image describe my problem better :

[image]

The Label.Left = 100 here.
Which Control should i use in Crystal Reports to do this?

Comment: Explain your situation a bit more. Perhaps you can solve it using sections.

Comment: Rather than telling the issue in that line, you can let us know what finally you want to achieve. Using sections can be far better idea.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure that i get your problem but i think this can help you.
in c#.net you can use left and top to add your object to crystal report
for example this code:

```
            CRAXDRT.Report report1 = new CRAXDRT.Report();
            CRAXDRT.Application app1 = new CRAXDRT.Application();
            report1 = app1.OpenReport("Test.rpt", OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByDefault);
            CRAXDRT.OleObject to3 = report1.Sections[1].AddPictureObject("YourPhoto.bmp", 0, 0);
            to3.Left = 100;
            to3.Top = 20;                
            to3.Height = 500;
            to3.Width = 600;
```